# Unique, multi-dimensional array in Classic ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, active-directory

I am trying to produce an organisational structure chart using ASP Classic. The code I am working on uses a single LDAP query to get all information for the sake of performance. I have the following code:

```
 <%@ Language="VBScript"%>
 <% response.Buffer = True
 dim ADUser 'Holds the OU
 dim RecordList 'Holds the RecordList object
 %>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <!--#include virtual="//includes/functions.asp"-->
 <!--#include virtual="//includes/display.asp"-->
 <h1>Organisational Structure</h1>
 <div class="commandspace">
 <p class="infotext">The org structure can be viewed with or without staff, indented or left justified.</p>
 </div>
 <% 
 ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=internal"
 ' Make AD connection and run query
 Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
 objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\User"
 objCon.Properties("Password") = "PaSsWoRd"
 objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
 objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
 objCom.CommandText ="select company, department, givenName, sn, title, telephoneNumber FROM '"& ADUser &"' where company ='*'" 
 Set objRS = objCom.Execute
 RecordList = objRS.GetRows()
 ' Loop over returned recordset and output HTML
 for i = 0 to uBound(RecordList, 2)
      u = i + 1
      if RecordList(5,i) <> RecordList(5,u) then
           Response.Write "<div class='Structure_Item_1'>" & RecordList(5,i) & "</div>" & vbCrLf
      end if
      if RecordList(4,i) <> RecordList(4,u) then
           Response.Write "<div class='Structure_Item_2'>" & RecordList(4,i) & "</div>" & vbCrLf
      end if
      Response.Write  "<div class='Structure_Item_3'>" & RecordList(3,i) & " " & RecordList(2,i) & "</div>" &vbCrLf
 next
 objRS.Close
 objCon.Close
 Set objRS = Nothing
 Set objCon = Nothing
 Set objCom = Nothing
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The page will list the different service areas, departments within and people in the departments. My problem is that I am getting duplicate data.

I have considered putting the departments in a Scripting Dictionary but realise that won't work since it wouldn't be multidimensional, so I couldn't have the service area and the department in the same dictionary unless I set the service area as the key and the department as the value.

This would, however, mean that keys are not unique. The same would go for the department and the staff member name.

I was thinking of two arrays, one with the service areas and departments in, one with the department and staff name. I was planning to, then, do a comparison operation which would dictate the formatting

Help would be much appreciated. This made a bit more sense in my head I fear

Comment: This might be an artifact of sanitizing your code for posting purposes, but it looks like you're using the telephone number (column 5) and job title (column 4) as the headings for the "sn" (column 3), whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

This is either me missing your point completely, or you missing the forest for the trees, but if you're going to write out a heading every time a particular column changes, you need to make sure you've sorted by that column. Otherwise, you'll get repeats of the heading at random places. If you need multiple levels of headings, sort the corresponding columns in descending order of priority.

(Side note: you may want to close the recordset immediately after doing your `.Getrows`, and *then* go about fiddling with writing out the data. Otherwise, you might as well have not used Getrows.)